# Converting a data frame to a spatial object

Tags: r, r-sf, r-mapview, r-mapedit

I'm trying to publish a map on Shiny, but keep running into this issue.

Let's call the data.frame `region`. Here are the columns:

```
  library(mapedit)
  library(mapview)
  library(shiny)
  library(leaflet)
  library(leaflet.extras)   



  region$address
  region$city
  region$state
  region$zip
  region$county
  region$xcol (these are the longitude coordinates)
  region$ycol (these are the latitude coordinates)
```

But when I run the `mapview(region)@map` it produces the following error:

> Error: 
>   oops! Arguments xcol and/or ycol are missing!
>   You probably expected turf_clean to be a spatial object. 
>   However it is of class data.frame. 
>   Either convert turf_clean to a spatial object or provide xcol and ycol.

I provided the x and y cols, but it's still not producing what I need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The library `sf` and its `st_as_sf()` is a way to convert your data.frame to a spatial object.  `crs` refers to the datum and projection, which I just guessed assuming your lat/long are relative to the WGS84 datum. I believe the projection is what maps.google.com uses - web mercator auxiliary sphere.

```
library(sf)
turf_clean <- st_as_sf(region, coords = c("xcol", "ycol"), crs = 4326)
```

Comment: What exactly is `crs`? What does that mean?

Comment: @gooponyagrinch it means coordinate reference system. There may be better sites but a quick google returned this https://rspatial.org/spatial/6-crs.html?highlight=coordinate%20reference%20system